# Coolant leak 2006 Jeep Commander

Tags: jeep, coolant-leak

Took my Jeep Commander 4.7V8 RWD to dealership mech. cause I've been having to refill coolant container every couple of weeks. I've noticed small puddles of coolant after being parked for several hrs. (gen. area is behind passenger side wheel well). This has been going on for several months. Engine is not overheating, and waterpump has been replaced.  Mechanic cannot find the leak? Any ideas, tired of buying coolant. Jeep will traded in within 6 mos., so ok to continue refilling? Otherwise help! They're were other services recommeded at the shop, I'll tell you about those later, just currently concerned with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read, not a DIYer so any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't worry, it *will* get worse. At least it will get easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Other than coolant being a toxic substance that you'd be spreading around, no there isn't a specific reason you couldn't just keep refilling it. There is a risk involved, though. Either you'll forget to refill it (or someone else driving your car forgets), the leak gets suddenly worse, or your reservoir runs dry which introduces air pockets in your cooling system.

Personally, I wouldn't risk it. Find a reputable independent shop near you and at least get a second opinion. It's pretty shocking that they would give up on finding the coolant leak but hand you a list of other things to be done.

In the meantime, make sure that coolant reservoir stays full enough.

Comment: Right! That's what I thought too, especially since the leak is fairly steady? But yet they performed a "premium brake fluid service", is there such a thing? Anywho they made it seem necessary, and it cost me 148 bucks. For a grand total of $211.29, which included an oil/filter change.  On the list that they recommended be performed soon were transmission flush, power steering fluid flush, and rear differtial service? They kinda lost me after the $700+  quote. Yes I'll be trading in soon, thanks for the input.

Comment: I am surprised the Dealership gave up on finding the leak too. All dealerships are trained to offer every conceivable recommended or scheduled service under the sun because that is how they make their money. By their own definition, everything they do is "premium". :-D

Comment: There is one scenario where refilling coolant indefinitely would not work, for example, when coolant is leaking in oil compartment. Of course OP was quite explicit that coolant is leaking on the ground instead of "mysteriously" disappearing so this possibility is less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced my water pump a few months ago and now the water pump seal was leaking again.  My mechanic said the new pump was defective and he replaced it for free.  No more leak!

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? Can you be more specific how this will help the OP find the coolant leak around the passenger wheel well?

Answer (score -1):

just replaced water pump 2007 Commander,144000 miles,two weeks later leaking again. Brought back to shop, pump was defective at the seal, replaced for new one no charge, six weeks no more leaks.Same result as Carguy.